# How to capture group in recursive regex?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am trying to make a regex that matches filters as described in [Microsoft RestAPI Guidelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/master/Guidelines.md#97-filtering). I have made this regex which does match a filter string:

```
(\(([\s]*(?:and|or|not)?[\s]*([\w]+)[\s]+(?:eq|ne|gt|ge|lt|le)[\s]+(?:"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|\d+(,\d+)*(\.\d+(e\d+)?)?|null)[\s]*|(?R))*\))
```

But, it does not capture all the sub-patterns. For example, in this example string:

```
((priority eq "123" or en eq 34) and pre eq 1)
```

It returns two captures: (1) the entire string, (2) the last pattern `and pre eq 1`

I want to capture all the sub-patterns too. How can I do that?

Here is a link on Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/wH8iH1/8

Comment: What output should be?

Comment: I want each sub-pattern captured. So, priority eq "123",  or en eq 34, and pre eq 1 should be captured

Comment: Better use some kind of parser here.

Comment: Add regex flavor/language tag to your question please.

Comment: AFAIK that syntax **cannot** be parsed by regexes, since it can be arbitrarily nested. So give up and write a real parser instead.

Comment: You can't to use regular expressions to parse non-regular data.

Comment: I understand. So, I believe I will be writing a parser. Thanks for the help :)